# Elastic - Determining which field to query based on it's value

Tags: elasticsearch

Sorry if the question seems newb, I'm quite new to elastic.

I have a custom UI with user input field where users inputs his search and runs search over one index. I want to determine which field should I query based on user input whenever possible.

Example scenario: User inputs 18 -> I want to filter on age field. User inputs "Joe" -> I want to filter on name field, "developer" -> filter on job field. Moreover it would be awesome if ">18" would be interpreted as range query on age.

Would something like that be possible with just using elastic API or do I need a custom parsers/analyzer?

Comment: Best you can do is to full text search in all the fields

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnot exist. The concept of Elastic is to build your own search engine. So you have also to specify what to search and how. I dont know witch langage (and so client) you use, but it s very easy to split the different field and make different standard search class for each one.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesnot exist. but for simple use:

if u use .net--> u can use somthing like [NEST](http://Install-Package%20NEST%20-Version%206.4.0)

or for Java--> u can use something like [Java API [6.5] » Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html)

or...